# Can the file:///path/to/local/file/data.json URL be used with AFHTTPRequestOperation

Tags: objective-c, ios8, afnetworking-2

Is there a way to use AFHTTPRequestOperation to retrieve the contents of a local JSON test data file? The execution of following code snippet follows the failure code block. I suspect the problem is occurring because I'm using a URL with the file:/// construct. Is this assumption correct?

```
/** Get JSON from the local file **/

// Create an URL object set to the JSON endpoint.
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"file:///Users/charlie/Desktop/Xcode%20Projects/Assets/MyProfile.json"];

// Create a URL Load Request using the NSURL.
NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];

// Create an AFHTTPRequestOperation to perform the Internet call.
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
operation.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];


[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id jsonObject) {
    // If the request succeeds:
    NSLog(@"JSON is: %@", jsonObject);
}
                                 failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    // If the request fails:
    NSLog(@"%%ViewController-E-DEBUG, JSON request failed.");
}];

// Start the request operation.
[operation start];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use AFNetworking for local file data because AFNetworking is used for network task as this is not a network task so you can pick that file and parse that file locally using NSJsonSerialization.
As it is assumed that local file is in your project directory.

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:jsonFileName ofType:@"json"];//jsonfilename is the name of your file
NSData *JSONData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath options:NSDataReadingMappedIfSafe error:nil];
NSDictionary *jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:JSONData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
```